# How to do an update on a query having union in postgrsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have 2 tables  name test and test_snapshop. in test table i am saving the current data and in test_snapshot i am saving older data. Now i need to do an update against some id values.theer is a chance that some ids exist in test and some in snapshot table.

I tried like this

```
update test 
  set column1=value,
      column2=value,
      column3=value 
where column4 in(1,2,3)
union
update test_snapshot 
  set  column1=value,
       column2=value,
       column3=value 
where column4 in(1,2,3)
```

Both tables have same no and name of column.

The above query is not as expected. what I am doing wrong in this query. can any one help me in this.

I am new to postgresql.

Comment: Just run two updates. UNION is not supported for UPDATE and is not needed here either.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo.  The `union` is a typo.  Just run two separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

Although I voted to close as a typo, you can express this in Postgres using a single statement.  I might go for:

```
with ids as (
      select *
      from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(id)
     ),
     t as (
      update test 
          set column1 = value,
              column2 = value,
              column3 = value 
          where column4 in (select i.id from ids i)
     )
update test_snapshot 
    set column1 = value,
        column2 = value,
        column3 = value 
     where column4 in (select i.id from ids i);
```

With this structure, you only need to list the id values once.